# Errors at start of Perceptron Training

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pycharm

I have taken a large dataset (`32,000` records) and reduced it to `1,000` with some added and moved columns. No problems there, and everything displays/prints as expected. I load the revised dataset, which is a .csv file, convert it to a numpy array, and display the first 5 X rows and y values. No problems there.

I split the data into an 90/10 train/test split, and write print statements showing that there are the appropriate values in `X_train`, `X_test`, `y_train` and `y_test`. I assign a variable ppn to the Perceptron so it runs 40 epochs with a learning rate .1 and `random_state = 0`. No problems there. The issue comes in when I get to my command to start training the Perceptron and fit the data (`ppn.fit(X_train, y_train`), which displays a host of errors.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\homework0\homework1b.py", line 76, in <module>
    ppn.fit(X_train, y_train)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\homework0\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 1151, in wrapper
    return fit_method(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\homework0\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_stochastic_gradient.py", line 907, in fit
    return self._fit(
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\homework0\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_stochastic_gradient.py", line 694, in _fit
    self._partial_fit(
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\homework0\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_stochastic_gradient.py", line 586, in _partial_fit
    X, y = self._validate_data(
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\homework0\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 621, in _validate_data
    X, y = check_X_y(X, y, **check_params)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\homework0\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 1147, in check_X_y
    X = check_array(
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\homework0\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 917, in check_array
    array = _asarray_with_order(array, order=order, dtype=dtype, xp=xp)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\homework0\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_array_api.py", line 380, in _asarray_with_order
    array = numpy.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Local-gov'
```

I am not completely new to Python, but somewhat new to pandas and dataframes. I've imported all the necessary libraries, and I've resolved all other errors I had previously. I've looked at some of the files it references (venv\lib\site-packages...), but I'm not sure what I'm looking for, other than to stare at the line numbers they reference and shrug my shoulders. :-)

I used a `.csv` that I downloaded, corrected data, and then exported my newly created dataframe to a new .csv, which I am re-reading in for this next training step. I'm reading some things about "views" versus "copies", but I don't begin to know how/if that applies in this case, nor the differences.

Also, the ValueError: could not convert string to float is very odd. It gives differing values when I run my code multiple times. All of my data is either int64 or object. None of it is float, nor do I have any code that does any conversion to float.

Could someone how I would start to unravel this litany of errors? I'm happy to do more research, but I just need a push in the right direction. Perhaps I'm not fundamentally understanding how to apply Perceptron to this model of data?! Appreciate any support.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show some of your code?
With these stuff of output, I guess your data contains some columns with not float value (may be string, object), but Perceptron only get float value as input so you must transform those columns into float, you can consult One-Hot Encoding or Ordinal Encoding.

Comment: Thanks to Itgk03 for clarifying that Perceptron can only accept float, and not the string values like 'Local-gov' that I had in my dataset. The concept of replacing my data with numerical values wasn't clear to me until I had your clue and read more information. I have since converted all my data to use Integer (Ordinal) Encoding or One-Hot Encoding, and my trainer now produces results.